# Android Listview out of Sync

Tags: android, listview, synchronization

I am writing a music player app for tablets

The activity can be thought of as 3 sections

Left side of screen has a listview object that is used to navigate through folders

the center of the screen has a listview object that contains a list of songs found within the current selected folder

the right hand side of the screen contains the play controls.

When the user has navigated to a folder, they can play the list of files that are presented in the center column.    This is working 95% perfectly.

When a song completes, it moves to the next item in the center listview, and scrolls this to the list to place this at the top.

This can work perfectly for hours, the top item in the list being the current playing song.

However, sometimes the list in the center gets completely out of sync with the song that is playing, almost like it has been repopulated.  This tends to happen when the application has been running in the background.  However, this is so rare that I have been unable to track down what the cause could be.

The code to create the song list is called after the folder list has been been triggered.  This populates the center column, and stores the song list in memory.  The music player plays from memory.  However, if the song list were recreated, then the list in memory would be destroyed and surely they would still be in sync.

Does anybody have any suggestions?  Anything at all?  I'm sure it is to do with activity being created/recreated as the app is moved back into focus, but why doesn't this happen every time?

EDIT:  There is code to scroll the listview in the oncompletion listener.  Although the songs move to the next song after completion if the app isn't in focus on screen, would the list view be able to scroll?  And if not, why would this problem be intermittent?

When the activity is created, I do this:

mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

this relates to the code below:

```
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                // check for repeat is ON or OFF
                if(isRepeat){
                    // repeat is on play same song again
                    playSong(currentSongIndex);
                } 
                else{
                    // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
                    if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                        playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                        //filelv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0);
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                        {
                            filelv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0); 
                        }
                        else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
                        {
                            int firstVisible = filelv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                            int lastVisible = filelv.getLastVisiblePosition();
                            if (currentSongIndex < firstVisible)
                                filelv.smoothScrollToPosition(currentSongIndex);
                            else
                                filelv.smoothScrollToPosition(currentSongIndex + lastVisible - firstVisible - 2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filelv.setSelectionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0);
                        } 


                    }else{
                        // play first song
                        playSong(0);
                        currentSongIndex = 0;
                        filelv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.FileList);
                        //filelv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0);
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                        {
                            filelv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0); 
                        }
                        else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
                        {
                            int firstVisible = filelv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                            int lastVisible = filelv.getLastVisiblePosition();
                            if (currentSongIndex < firstVisible)
                                filelv.smoothScrollToPosition(currentSongIndex);
                            else
                                filelv.smoothScrollToPosition(currentSongIndex + lastVisible - firstVisible - 2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filelv.setSelectionFromTop(currentSongIndex, 0);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

The other thing that occurs is that my app is not yet configured to run as a service.  Could this be the cause?

Comment: Could you add some of the code you are using? Will allow us to help you more =)

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which bit to add without adding the whole lot!

Answer (score 1):

This error sounds like a context error or thread problems. If the app is in the background and android kills one of your processes when not needed anymore you might end up with really strange behavior. This would also be intermittent because of the timing and memory of other apps.

### First

- Are there any strange logs in log cat when this occures?

### Secondly

Then try to go through the code and look for anything suspicious.

- How is the creations of the list done.
- Do you have other threads running?
- Does anyone have a reference to the middle list.
- Are there any hanging `context objects` any where?

### Finally

It is very hard to fix an error if you don't have the means to reproduce it, so try to find a way to force it. Like: *make the app run in the background, and open a lot of other apps, and then go back to your music player again*. This can be done problematically so you don't have to do it yourself.

If you can find a way to reproduce it, then it is just to start eliminating code until you find the cause.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response.  The list is generated after the user clicks on a folder to play.  It is created in an asynctask.  The user then clicks play and the app happily starts to play the songs.  I'll have a look in the logcat but pretty sure that the app won't have reported anything strange.  Worth a look though.  Shortly after i posted the original question, I had left the app going, it was still in focus but the device had gone to lock screen then off.  Music carried on playing.  However, when i went back to the app, the list was out of sync. When the song ended, it moved back into sync

Comment: Then you update method was called when the music ended! Be sure to check that out also. If you can: try to reduce all the code to a minimum and post it here.